# Matrix of quadratic form has to be symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

[On Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_%28quadratic_form%29#Real_quadratic_forms) it is stated that any $n\times n$ real *symmetric* matrix A determines a quadratic form. But isn't $ax^2 + bxy + cxy + dy^2$, the quadratic form given by $v^T A v$ with $A=\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$ and $v=\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$, a quadratic form even when $c \neq b$?

Why does the Wikipedia article state that the matrix has to be symmetric?

Comment: You have to combine the $bxy$ and $cxy$ terms...

Comment: The section you linked to is about forms over $\mathbb{R}$, which has characteristic not equal to 2.  Over such fields, we do not get any new quadratic form by considering non-symmetric matrices because we can divide by 2.  So $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ gives the same quadratic form as $\begin{pmatrix} a & \frac{b+c}{2} \\ \frac{b+c}{2} & d \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @MichaelWijaya Thank you, this answers my question. Now I understand that symmetry is only required when division by 2 is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that the matrix $A$ can be made symmetric without loss of generality. Simply define the off-diagonal elements of $A$ in your example to be $(b+c)/2$.