# A "quadratic form" $x\mapsto x^TAx$ in which $A$ is not symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, quadratic-forms

Let $n \in \{1,2,\dots\}$, and let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix of real numbers. Consider the unique function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(x) = x^TAx$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $A$ is not symmetric.

1. Is it possible for $f$ to be convex?
2. Suppose that $f(x) \geq 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Must $f$ be convex? What if $f(x) > 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$?
3. Is $A$ uniquely determined by $f$? In other words, suppose that $B$ is an $n\times n$ matrix of real numbers satisfying that $f(x) = x^TBx$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$; is it necessarily the case that $A=B$?

Comment: At least question 3 has been asked many times before (in different variations); https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307381/why-do-we-assume-that-a-matrix-in-quadratic-form-is-symmetric, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1464994/symmetric-part-of-a-contributes-to-quadratic-form, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3580859/quadratic-form-if-corresponding-matrix-is-not-symmetric-matrix, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420917/matrix-of-quadratic-form-has-to-be-symmetric, and so on...

Comment: @HansLundmark: Thanks. Actually, question 3 is the only one of the three question I asked that is not answered by any of the posts you linked to...

Comment: Of course it's answered. The quadratic forms are equal iff the symmetric parts of $A$ and $B$ are equal, i.e. $(A+A^t)/2=(B+B^t)/2$. So $A$ is definitely *not* uniquely determined by $f$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1964244/339790)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
x^TAx = \sum_{i,j}x_i A_{ij} x_j = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}x_i (A_{ij} +A_{ji})x_j = x^TBx,
$$
where
$$
B = \frac{A+A^T}{2}
$$
is symmetric.
Thus, all the properties true for a symmetrix $A$ matrix apply.